# How to passg customer token into IBM Watson Assistant

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant, watson-assistant-solutions

I want to use various fields such as customer token, customer id etc. in each session created in watson assistant v2 using nodejs.

Can I pass it directly in the createSession function or do I need to create an entitiy or intent for it to pass in Watson Assistant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it with the message where you want to use it. See the **context** parameter in that [message API function](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node#send-user-input-to-assistant). This could be the first message. The context usually stays unchanged until you overwrite the values or [delete the context variable](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime#dialog-runtime-context-delete).